# Insert several values into one column of a SQL table

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a list of about 22,000 ids that I would like to insert into one SQL table. The table contains only one column which will contain all of the 22,000 ids.

How can I populate the column with all of these values in one query? Thanks.

Comment: What type of file are you using and how are they separated?

Comment: Single column table means that column will be your PI.  If you don't care about duplicate rows, you may want to create your table as MULTISET. 
 22,000 rows isn't a lot, but if your table gets much bigger, you may get a performance hit due to the duplicate row check on your INSERT.

Comment: The ids are in an excel file and I'd love to import them into a table with one column for id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends (as usual) where you have the values.

If the values reside in a table it is just `insert into <yourTargetTable> select <yourColumns> from <yourSourceTable>`.

If you have the values in a file, one way could be to load it with bteq's `.import`command. See an example here https://community.teradata.com/t5/Tools-Utilities/BTEQ-examples/td-p/2466

Other options: SQL-Assistant, TD-Studio, TPT, Easy Loader ...

Serach for `teradata import data from text file` and you'll get a lot of answers.